# Cout 2D Array to console C++

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

I'm having issues getting a 2D array to display to the console correctly. Currently, it displays as such

```
Ally Baba's Burgers
-------------------
B Burger 3
S 
Soda 1
F Fries 
2
C Chips 1.5 

-------------------
X - Clear Sale
T - Total
E - End Shift

Enter command:
```

I would like it to display as

```
Ally Baba's Burgers
-------------------
B Burger 3
S Soda 1
F Fries 2
C Chips 1.5 
-------------------
X - Clear Sale
T - Total
E - End Shift

Enter command:
```

The text file that I'm getting the menu options from looks exactly the same as above, minus the cout I am inserting.

```
void getMenu(string menu[][3]){

    string line;
    ifstream file("Menu.txt");

    if (!file){
        cout << "File failed to opened\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j <3; ++j){
            if (getline(file, line, ' ')){
                menu[i][j] = line;
            }
        }
     }
 file.close();
}

void displayMenu(string menu[][3], char & choice){
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Ally Baba's Burgers\n";
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            cout << menu[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout << "X - Clear Sale" << endl;
    cout << "T - Total" << endl;
    cout << "E - End Shift\n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter command: ";
    cin >> choice;
}
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: Somehow you have stored a `'\n'` **after** `S` and `Fries` or **before** `Soda` or `C` -- impossible to tell without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but likely the `'\n'` is left in `stdin` after a call to something like `cin >> choice;`.

Comment: `getline(file, line, ' ')` reads until the next space, so when you read the last item in a line it will also read the first item in the next line since a newline is not a space.

Comment: @BessieTheCow wouldn't `(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)` stop this from happening it is only able to run through the loop 3 time?

Comment: The loop only runs 3 times, but in the last iteration `getline` will read the next two items since they are separated by a newline instead of a space.

Answer (score 1):

As @BessieTheCow pointed, getline is reading until the next space is found. Use without this or specify the new line delimiter instead.

Supposing that your Menu.txt file ends each line while a new line delimiter, do:

```
void getMenu(string menu[][3]){

    string line;
    ifstream file("Menu.txt");

    if (!file){
        cout << "File failed to opened\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j <3; ++j){
            if (getline(file, line)){
                menu[i][j] = line;
            }
        }
     }
 file.close();
}
```